# TypeError: unknown type returned

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs5, ngrx

I am using **ngrx/effects**. I got this error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: unknown type returned

This is part of my codes:

```
  this.store.dispatch({ type: CHAT_LOAD_MESSAGES, payload: chatId });

  @Effect() loadMessages$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction(CHAT_LOAD_MESSAGES)
    .map<string>(toPayload)
    .do(chatId => console.log('chatId', chatId))    // Here I can get chatId
    .switchMapTo(chatId => this.chatService.loadMessages(chatId))  // The error comes out because of this line
    .do(res => console.log('res', res))             // This didn't run
    .map((messages: Message[]) => ({ type: CHAT_LOAD_MESSAGES_SUCCESS, payload: messages }));
```

---

```
  loadMessages(chatId: string): Observable<Message[]> {
    // This is what I am using to test right now.
    // Maybe this line is wrong? How can I write correct simulation?
    return Observable.of([{ id:1, content:'Hi' });
  }
```

What may cause this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @apreg point out my error on Gitter.

I should change `switchMapTo` to `switchMap`.

The official document and explanation of [switchMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap) and [switchMapTo](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMapTo).