# Angular 2 effect is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

Reducer:

```
import {ActionReducer, Action} from '@ngrx/store';

import {SET_BRANDS, SET_BRAND} from './brands.actions';
import {IBrandsStorage} from './brands-storage.interface';

export const BrandsReducer: ActionReducer<any> = (state: IBrandsStorage = {list: [], single: {}}, action: Action) => {

  switch(action.type) {

    case SET_BRANDS: return Object.assign({}, state, {
      list: [...action.payload.data]
    });

    case SET_BRAND: return Object.assign({}, state, {
      single: action.payload.data
    });
  }
}
```

Effect:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Action, Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import {Actions, Effect} from '@ngrx/effects';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

import {GET_BRANDS, GET_BRAND} from './brands.actions';
import {BrandsApi} from 'app/shared/apis';

@Injectable()

export class BrandsEffects {

  constructor(private brandsApi: BrandsApi, private store: Store, private actions$: Actions) {}

  @Effect() brands$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(GET_BRANDS)
    .switchMap(() => this.brandsApi.getBrands())
    .map(brands => this.store.dispatch({type: SET_BRANDS, payload: brands}))
    // TODO: Add a catch

  @Effect() brand$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(GET_BRAND)
    .switchMap(() => this.brandsApi.getBrand())
    .map(brand => this.store.dispatch({type: SET_BRAND, payload: brand}))
    // TODO: Add a catch
}
```

And in component in `ngOnInit` I call this:

```
this.store.dispatch({type: GET_BRANDS});
```

And the error that is thrown is `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: unknown type returned`, I'm guessing that this is because I haven't defined it in the reducer. But I don't want to define `GET_BRANDS` in the reducer as it won't do anything to my state, I just want to have `SET` methods in my reducer to set the data I get from the api.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it though, can someone shed some light on this?

**EDIT:**

I tried to add a `GET_BRANDS` action to the reducer which just set some `isBusy` state to `true` but it gives me the same error so I'm not sure what is the issue..

I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035214/typeerror-unknown-type-returned) which suggests switching `switchMapTo` to `switchMap` but I'm already using `switchMap`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it with:

```
.map(brands => ({type: SET_BRANDS, payload: brands}))
```

You don't need to use store.dispatch.

Did you imported SET_BRANDS from actions in your **BrandsEffects**? It seams not.

Comment: Removing dispatch was also needed since I got a weird error in other reducers when using it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was the `brandsApi` which was at fault, as it didn't return an `Observable`, but rather some test data I had as normal JSON. When I changed it to an actual request it got past the `switchMap` without any problems.